# Is Greek mythology derivative of/influence by Ugartic/Canaanite mythology?

Tags: greek, comparative, ugaritic

I know that the character of 'Adonis' is of Phoenician origin, but there are many other parallels which are too many to be ignored:

Phosporus- Shahar

Hesperus- Shalim

Zeus/Poseidon/Hades- Baal/Yamm/Mot

Athena- Anat

Aphrodite- Astarte

Heracles- Melqart

And is there a possible link between Pandora and the Biblical Eve?

Comment: I'm not sure parallels in a few deities is really that big of a deal though. With a large enough pantheon, individual gods are bound to have traits/aspects that are present in another pantheon - they're all derived from natural observations after all.

Answer (score 5):

As Gibet noted, there are similarities between Baal and Zeus but they're pretty loose.

However, if you're looking for a [Near Eastern analogue](http://www.classics.upenn.edu/myth/php/hesiod/index.php?page=eastern) to Zeus and Kronos, you need to go to the [Hittite/Hurrian](http://stason.org/TULARC/education-books/hittite-hurrian-mythology/01-Who-were-the-Hittites.html) myth of Kingship in Heaven, which is very similar to the story of Ouranos-Kronos-Zeus.

The middle god, Kumarbi, even bites off his father's genitals, just like Kronos castrated Ouranos, but in the [Hittite myth](https://www.bibliotecapleyades.net/sitchin/guerradioses/guerradioses05a.htm) Kumarbi becomes pregnant with three gods, and has to spit them out from his belly. When the Storm-God Teshub takes power there's a battle between him and Kumarbi, just like the Titans and Olympians.

PS - This paper ([pdf](http://grbs.library.duke.edu/article/viewFile/12791/1881)) discusses similarites in the Kingship in Heaven theme across Greece and the Near East generally.